# Split form across 2 divs with CakePHP

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

I'm making a form that I'd like to be 2 columns, however, cake is closing the form after the first column. I'm using Cake 2.3.8

The first column is styled fine, but the second column has shorter spacing between the inputs. I checked the source and cake is adding the closing form tag after the first column, which I'm guessing explains the styling issue of the second column.

```
<div class = "template_form_left">  
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->create('Template');

            echo $this->Form->input('bullet_1', array('label' => 'Bullet 1'));
            echo $this->Form->input('bullet_2', array('label' => 'Bullet 2'));
            echo $this->Form->input('bullet_3', array('label' => 'Bullet 3'));

            echo $this->Form->input('section_1_title', array('label' => 'Section 1 Title'));
            echo $this->Form->input('section_1_content', array('label' => 'Section 1 Content'));

            echo $this->Form->input('section_2_title', array('label' => 'Section 2 Title'));
            echo $this->Form->input('section_2_content', array('label' => 'Section 2 Content'));

     //when I check the source, a closing form tag is added here by cake    
        ?>
</div>
<div class = "template_form_right"> 
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('section_3_title', array('label' => 'Section 3 Title'));
            echo $this->Form->input('section_3_content', array('label' => 'Section 3 Content'));


            echo $this->Form->input('section_4_title', array('label' => 'Section 4 Title'));
            echo $this->Form->input('section_4_content', array('label' => 'Section 4 Content'));

            echo $this->Form->input('section_5_title', array('label' => 'Section 5 Title'));
            echo $this->Form->input('section_5_content', array('label' => 'Section 5 Content'));

            echo $this->form->submit('Submit');
        ?>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.template_form_left{
float:left;
width:50%
}

.template_form_right{
float:right;
width:50%
}
```

Aside from using a table or manually coding the form, is it possible to split a form up across two divs so they appear side by side (2 columns) while still using the form helper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really a cakePHP problem.

What you're trying to do is have

```
<div class="left">
    <form>
    ...
</div>
<div class="right">
    ...
    </form>
<div>
```

which is not valid HTML and is illogical. Think you're telling the browser: "Start a drawer that contains a closet and then finish the drawer, start another and finish the closet and then the drawer".

Each browser will attempt to save the day and format it the best it can but with unpredictable results.

Instead what you need to say is:

```
<form>
    <div class="left">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        ...
    </div>
</form>
```

or "Start a closet start a drawer, stop a drawer, start a drawer, stop a drawer, stop closet". This translates in your code as:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Template'); ?>
<div class = "template_form_left"> 
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('bullet_1', array('label' => 'Bullet 1'));
    echo $this->Form->input('bullet_2', array('label' => 'Bullet 2'));
    echo $this->Form->input('bullet_3', array('label' => 'Bullet 3'));

    echo $this->Form->input('section_1_title', array('label' => 'Section 1 Title'));
    echo $this->Form->input('section_1_content', array('label' => 'Section 1 Content'));

    echo $this->Form->input('section_2_title', array('label' => 'Section 2 Title'));
    echo $this->Form->input('section_2_content', array('label' => 'Section 2 Content')); ?>
</div>
<div class = "template_form_right">
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('section_3_title', array('label' => 'Section 3 Title'));
    echo $this->Form->input('section_3_content', array('label' => 'Section 3 Content'));


    echo $this->Form->input('section_4_title', array('label' => 'Section 4 Title'));
    echo $this->Form->input('section_4_content', array('label' => 'Section 4 Content'));

    echo $this->Form->input('section_5_title', array('label' => 'Section 5 Title'));
    echo $this->Form->input('section_5_content', array('label' => 'Section 5 Content')); ?>
</div> 
<?php
echo $this->form->submit('Submit');
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up switching to fieldsets instead of divs after researching what you said. Guess I don't know HTML as well as I thought.

Comment: And if you want your submit button somewhere else, simply do `echo $this->Form->button('Submit');` on the location where you want the submit button to be. That way you can have the button in the second column for example.